# Docker Laravel not loading assets

Tags: laravel, apache, docker, docker-compose

I have configure a docker compose file to run laravel with apache and mysql. The app builds fine but when i access to it i have this error loading the assets

[image: Console errors]
This is my docker-compose file conf:

```
    version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  vma_web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: vma_web
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: '.env.prod'
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8250:80"
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: vma_web
      SERVICE_TAGS: 1.0.0
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  vma_mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: vma_mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "33061:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: school_back
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: epTfkgH9XakwN5mm
      SERVICE_TAGS: 1.0.0
      SERVICE_NAME: vma_mysql
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

And the dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-apache-stretch
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libxml2-dev nano zip unzip
RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring gd zip pdo pdo_mysql
COPY vma.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
WORKDIR /var/www/html/vma
COPY . .
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN chmod -R 777 bootstrap storage public routes/pages.php
RUN composer install
EXPOSE 80
```

What am i doing wrong ?
is something about permissions ?
is something about the ports ?